# How do I turn off the click sound when closing a tab in Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Every time I close a tab in Chrome, it makes a click sound. How do I turn off that sound?

I reported that issue back in [Oct 2010](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58359). The problem doesn't appear on all clients and the reason is still unclear.

[Common attempts at solving the issue](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/L-jTsQelNN0) include simply turning off the sound in Windows. But I would prefer to solve the problem at the source.

Why is Chrome even triggering that sound to be played? And why is it delayed? The problem would be far less annoying if the sound could easily be related to the action taken.

- Installing the [Chrome Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn) and muting all tabs has no effect on this issue.
- When switching to a different Chrome user profile, the new user profile does exhibit the same issue.
- Only Adblock is installed.

This didn't happen until recently. I don't know whether it's Chrome or the OS, but a clicking sound appears when a tab is closed nonetheless.

Comment: Google chrome doesn't make sounds when closing tabs (or anything else) as far as i know. Do you run any extensions that might be doing this?
Else you can check the sound settings of your Operating System.

Comment: Only adblock is installed. This didn't happen until recently. I don't know whether its chorme or the OS, but a clicking sound appears when a tab is closed nontheless.

Comment: Does this happen when you close a tab using the keyboard (Ctrl-W) and/or the mouse?

Comment: I think this has to do with the current process model setup in chrome. Try changing

Comment: I get a sound, too. It does not occur with CTRL+W, but does if I use the mouse. It also plays when I hit buttons on the menu bar. There's no mention of this in the settings/preferences... so I'm muting my whole audio system to solve it. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04. Help!

Comment: I get this problem too, but only occasionally. I don't know what I do to make this start happening, and I _think_ restarting Chrome makes it go away. I am almost suspicious of some kind of malware working behind the scenes.

Comment: Which versions of Windows and Chrome are you hearing this in? Is the tab close sound the same or different than the window close sound?

Comment: I just got this issue this morning. What’s odd is that it was not happening last night before I put the system to sleep and only showed up this morning for seemingly no reason after waking it and running Chrome. I checked services, processes, extensions, and plugins, but found nothing suspicious or unusual, so I’m at a complete loss as to what it could be. However, I’ll note that after closing Chrome altogether (and making sure there are no residual `chrome.exe` processes left) and running it again, there is no more clicking (I also stopped a few services, but none of them should be relevant).

Answer (score 26):

For completeness sake, it should be noted that (at least in mine and [someone elses](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58359) case), rebooting the computer fixes the issue.

I rarely reboot, so the problem doesn't *fix itself* for me.
Also, this is a temporary fix for the issue. *Something* triggers it to reappear some time in the future, I just can't figure out what it is.

### Investigation

I tried to see what API functions are invoked by Chrome when the issue appears. For that, I ran the 32bit [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) and added a capture filter for calls into `winmm.dll`.

I checked if Chrome even calls [`PlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909766.aspx) (assuming that's how the sound is played) and it seems like it doesn't. I see a lot of other stuff happening when a tab is closed. But I wasn't able to pinpoint anything as the cause of the sound.

I'm now more confident that, while Chrome is the cause of the sound, it does not directly invoke it. I'm currently assuming that an action Chrome is taking is causing another process to emit the sound.

While investigating a few minutes ago, I started killing processes to see if and when the click sound would stop.

It stopped after closing all Windows Explorer windows. At this point it's unclear if there is any relation between Windows Explorer and the click sound being emitted. It'll have to wait for another day.

After the issue just happened again, I ran another Process Monitor recording and double-checked my Windows Explorer theory. Look what I got:

[image]

After closing the 2 open Explorer windows, the clicking was gone again.

In light of this new information, I decided to post [another bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163099).

Comment: See this [discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/oes5LXN44x4) & this [forum help](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=65117) may be they work for you.

Comment: "Surely a virus." ahhahaahahahhaha. Anyway, reboot solved for me. For now at least. The CTRL click is a good one on the mailing list.

Comment: Closing all open Explorer windows worked for me.

Comment: Closing all open explorer windows worked for me, definitely worth trying if you're experiencing this issue.

Comment: I closed and re-opened explorer and... WTF? It worked! What the heck is even going on here??

Comment: `rebooting the computer fixes the issue` That’s not necessary, simply [restarting Chrome is enough](http://superuser.com/questions/129790/#comment618317_129790). It happened to me again today while I was browsing (Chrome was running, I had tabs open, I closed tabs without sound, then suddenly it started out of *nowhere*. Restarting Chrome got rid of it just like last time.

Comment: `At this point it's unclear if there is any relation between Windows Explorer and the click sound being emitted. It'll have to wait for another day.` That’s what’s so curious about it (aside from it suddenly appearing out of nowhere). That noise we hear is the “navigation” noise which both Windows Explorer *and IE* make when you browse the system/web. The only connection between Chrome and either Explorer or IE is Chrome Frame, but that’s supposed to embed a Chrome frame in IE, not the other way around, so there really is no conceivable connection. ಠ_ఠ (That there’s a *delay* could be a clue…)

Comment: @Synetech: Interesting. I'll keep that in mind the next time it happens. In the past I've only restarted Windows Explorer to get rid of the behavior. Thanks for your input! If you find out anything else, please share :)

Comment: Didn't close chrome. Just closed all the windows explorer windows and the clicking went away.

Comment: I just had this now (again, had it a couple times in the past)  Restarted Chrome twice.  Nope, didn't fix it.  Googled... ah, yes, closing Windows Explorer does it.  Tried... yup, as in the past, that's *somehow* the cause.

Answer (score 19):

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Open Sounds. (In Windows 7 It's called Sounds not Sounds and Audio Devices)
3. In Sounds tab on Windows Explorer section, select Start Navigation
4. On Sounds section, select (None) on the drop down menu.
5. Apply then OK

[image]

<sub>[Kudos for HowToGeek for supplying this nice image](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-off-windows-explorer-click-sounds-in-windows-vista/)</sub>

Related question [Windows 7 'click' sound](https://superuser.com/questions/260931/windows-7-click-sound)

Comment: Here is the [link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3249b59f42654520&hl=en) to the original post on the Chrome forums.

Comment: What if he wants the clicking in other programs? This doesn't fix Chrome, specifically.

Comment: Any ideas how to do the same thing in KDE?

Comment: Um, **no**! This only *hides* the problem, it does not *fix* it. Chrome has never used the sound before; something has *changed* (that is not supposed to have). Simply muting it is *not* a solution!               (Patient: *It hurts when I breathe.*     Doctor: *Then don’t breathe.*)

Comment: To me this is the best solution. Honestly the sound is annoying **no matter where it is played**. I really hate it when I get this sound as I'm navigating folders in Windows Explorer. Yes it should be classified as a bug for how the sound is played in Chrome, but I'd say it's totally worth it to just disable this sound for the entire system. I don't get why Microsoft even introduced this junk setting and gave it a default sound.

Answer (score 0):

This annoying problem appeared spontaneously while I was browsing.

It is simply solved by closing all folders(windows explorer windows).

I can't say what triggered it, but I can say that I've had a few pdf files (stored on my computer) opened in Chrome. I've also had ONLY the current Donwloads target folder opened. These could all be possible triggers.

Answer (score -1):

my lappy had it too and for mine it was just the 'sound on click' extension for my google chrome browser. You can just go to settings > extensions then disable it or straight away delete it. hope it helped!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The OP stated he only has adblock installed.