# Windows 7 'click' sound

Tags: windows-7

Press a button.  "Click."  Or actually more like an amplified "Ca-chunck-klunk."  In Control Panel, which sound clip is it, so that it can be silenced?

Comment: What button are you talking about? Keyboard key? Non-standard keyboard button? The power button on the case? The optical drive open/close button?

Comment: Pretty sure this is relevant to Vista and XP as well. Possibly even older versions, although I assume the sound itself has changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is found under Sounds > Windows Explorer > "Start Navigation" sound

[image]

<sub>[Kudos for HowToGeek for supplying this nice image](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-off-windows-explorer-click-sounds-in-windows-vista/)</sub>

Comment: That's the one.  Thanks.  How do I silence it?  MS used to put check boxes next to those sounds.  Now all I see is a "Startup" check box.

Comment: This sound is the most annoying thing in the world! Is there anyone who benefits from hearing every time they click a link? A close runner up is the typing sound on the iphone.

Comment: You'll need to select the "Start Navigation" event, and use the drop down of .wavs, scroll all the way up and choose (None)

Comment: Whew! Thanks Zero. Sheep, I've been using iPhones only in the Stores and haven't typed much on them to even remember what the audio sounds like exactly (although I can easily imagine). I'm on the HTCs most of the time. Now when I first encountered haptic on those, I thought, I gotta turn this off--but I quickly started to really like haptic, particularly the fine, subtle one on the HTC.

Comment: So I already have this "Start Navigation" set to "(None)" but in Chrome, I still get that click sound when I follow a link to a new page. Can't find anything in the Chrome settings... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Select the Start Navigation. Then the Sounds selection list shows Windows Navigation Start.wav. Drop down it, and select the top (None), and OK. After it, there will be no start navigation sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the desktop and select personzalize, you can turn off the sounds option for the Aero theme. If there are other issues with Aero, you can check out this troubleshooting page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-problems-with-Windows-Aero